# Regex Look-Behind for Right to Left event

Tags: .net, regex, lookbehind, right-to-left

I'm extracting the events ending with Windows LogonIDs... this means like:

> `Special Privileges assigned to a new Logon: Logon Id: 0x007d`

I thought this is the best way to do it:

```
^(?<event>.+)(?<=ID:\s\d+x[A-F\d]+)$
```

Using **RegexOptions.RightToLeft** to start the search from the End of the String.

Using **lookbehind** so If the {ID: LogonId} didn't exists it will fail as fast as it can.

As I can't find any good Right To Left tester I'm here, asking for your help.

Comment: Might be helpful to put up some sample data...

Comment: Have you found the simplest regexp to be too slow in actual practice, or just in theory?

Comment: In practice, I'm using RegexBuddy Debugger, the problem is i can't test my regex the way i want because it not support RightToLeft processing.

Comment: I understand.  Have you tested the regex _the way you don't want_, for example as suggested by Alan Moore below?  It might very well be fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get the position of the match? In Perl, one could do:

```
if ($str =~ /ID:\s\d+x[A-F\d]+$/i)
   say substr($str, 0, $-[0]);  # $-[0] is the starting pos of the match.
}
```

or

```
if ($str =~ /ID:\s\d+x[A-F\d]+$/ip)
   say ${^PREMATCH};
}
```

Comment: well actually i need the regex for comparison, not extracting purpose.
I'm using it with GroupByEvaluator for Infragistics Grid.

Comment: @celerno, If you don't need to extract, why not just use the fastest of `/^.*ID:\s\d+x[A-F\d]+$/i` (l-to-r and r-to-l) and `/ID:\s\d+x[A-F\d]+$/i` (l-to-r and r-to-l).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong on my last comment. In fact, I would be extracting, because i need to compare All the text except (ID: 0x007d) against another who will have other ID, lets say ID: 0x008x.

The main issue is to find the exact pattern ID: 0x008x with the best performance... And if it not match, failing to found as fast as can.

 An Index could be great if i can't properly test my regex.

Thanks for you idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need the RightToLeft option **or** a lookbehind.  Have you tested it with a regex like this:

```
(?i)^(?<event>.+)ID:\s\d+x[A-F\d]+$
```

...and found it to be too slow?

Comment: Well, i'm trying the RightToLeft because i'm looking for strings that end with "ID: 0x0074"

The best performance is the key here. This regex is being used to sort and group  100,000 grids.

Comment: Well, if you have a text near to 400 characters log, and this event has an ID: somewhere, the processor will go from end to first trying to look for the static pattern ID: and the dinamic pattern \s\dx[A-F\d]+$